# 'foo.bar.com.s3.amazonaws.com' doesn't match either of '*.s3.amazonaws.com', 's3.amazonaws.com'

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I'm using django, and things like imgs I store at s3 (for this I'm using boto), but recently I got this error:

> 'foo.bar.com.s3.amazonaws.com' doesn't match either of
>   '*.s3.amazonaws.com', 's3.amazonaws.com'

I'm searching for a possible solution for about two days, but the unique things that is suggested is to change boto's source code, however I can't do this on production.

Edit: Using Django 1.58, Boto 2.38.0

Any help would be appreciated.
Thx in advance.

Comment: What worked for me is this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37706165/3997052

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this monkey patch in your connection.py file (boto/connection.py):

```
import ssl

_old_match_hostname = ssl.match_hostname

def _new_match_hostname(cert, hostname):
   if hostname.endswith('.s3.amazonaws.com'):
      pos = hostname.find('.s3.amazonaws.com')
      hostname = hostname[:pos].replace('.', '') + hostname[pos:]
   return _old_match_hostname(cert, hostname)

ssl.match_hostname = _new_match_hostname
```

([source](https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/2836))

another solution is in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37689708/how-can-i-solve-certificateerror-by-aws-s3-in-django/37706165#37706165):

Comment: this works for me until I was on python2. But during migration on python3, it gives me error `certificate is not valid for '*.s3.amazonaws.com'`. For me helps usage of `boto3` instead of `boto`

Answer (score 7):

As has been said, the problem occurs in buckets containing dots on name. Below just an example that prevents this.

```
import boto
from boto.s3.connection import VHostCallingFormat

c = boto.connect_s3(aws_access_key_id='your-access-key',
                    is_secure=False,
                    aws_secret_access_key='your-secret-access',
                    calling_format=VHostCallingFormat())
b = c.get_bucket(bucket_name='your.bucket.with.dots', validate=True)
print(b)
```

Comment: FWIW, `VHostCallingFormat` didn't work for me (getting 403 when writing to s3), but `OrdinaryCallingFormat` from the same module did.

Comment: @georg 's recommendation should be added to ECC response and it looks like a proper solution.

Comment: Same here, `VHostCallingFormat` led to `gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known` but `OrdinaryCallingFormat` worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

It's an known issue : [#2836](https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/2836). It's due to dots in your bucket name.
I had this issue some days before. A user seems to have succeeded to fix this by setting :

```
AWS_S3_HOST = 's3-eu-central-1.amazonaws.com'
AWS_S3_CALLING_FORMAT = 'boto.s3.connection.OrdinaryCallingFormat
```

But it didn't work for me.

Otherwise, you can create a bucket without points (**E.g** : `foo-bar-com`). It will work. This is what I did to temporarily fix this issue.

Comment: I tried to use what you said that fixed for a user, but for me i just get a 301 Moved Permanently

Comment: I get this error too. That's why I renamed my bucket

Comment: The problem is that i cannot change the bucker nor the bucket name. 
But Thanks for your attention

Comment: you can't create another one?

Comment: I'd created another bucket but still getting a 301 Moved Permanently

Comment: yeah but remove `AWS_S3_CALLING_FORMAT` and `AWS_S3_HOST`, go back to your previous configuration. it should work

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error when I moved from python3.4 to python3.5 (boto version remained the same).

The problem was solved by moving from boto to **boto3** package.

Example:

```
import boto3
s3_client = boto3.client("s3", aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key, aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_key)
body = open(local_filename, 'rb').read()
resp = s3_client.put_object(ACL="private", Body=body, Bucket=your_bucket_name, Key=path_to_the_file_inside_the_bucket)
if resp["ResponseMetadata"]["HTTPStatusCode"] != 200:
        raise Exception("Something went wrong...")
```