# How can i solve CertificateError by AWS -S3 in Django?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3

Here is the application hosted on heroku + aws s3 used for storing only media files. 
When user upload's a images the error occures .

```
 CertificateError at /create/
 hostname 'shuboy.media.s3.amazonaws.com' doesn't match either of '*.s3.amazonaws.com', 's3.amazonaws.com'
 Request Method:    POST
 Request URL:   http://shuboy2015.herokuapp.com/create/
 Django Version:    1.9.6
 Exception Type:    CertificateError
 Exception Value:   
 hostname 'shuboy.media.s3.amazonaws.com' doesn't match either of '*.s3.amazonaws.com', 's3.amazonaws.com'
 Exception Location:    /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/ssl.py in match_hostname, line 271
 Python Executable: /app/.heroku/python/bin/python
 Python Version:    2.7.10
 Python Path:   
 ['/app',
  '/app/.heroku/python/bin',
  '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-20.4-py2.7.egg',
  '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg',
  '/app',
  '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python27.zip',
  '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7',
  '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
  '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
  '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
  '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
  '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
 Server time:   Tue, 7 Jun 2016 20:54:31 +0000
```

In settings.py file , I only want to store media files there no static files.

```
 DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
 AWS_S3_SECURE_URLS = False   
 AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False     
 AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '*******'
 AWS_S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '******'
 AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME ='shuboy.media'
 AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME     



 STATIC_URL = '/static/'
 MEDIA_URL = 'https://%s/media/' % AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN     

 STATICFILES_DIRS = [
     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "appname/static"),
 ]     

 STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "STATIC_CDN")     

 MEDIA_ROOT = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com/media/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME     

 STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

If anybody tell me why this error is occurring and how can I solve this issue ? Any further suggestions will be appreciable .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The above error is happening because your bucket name has a "." in it.

The work around for this issue is go to `~/.boto` configuration file search for `https_validate_certificates` and set it to `False` it will work.

Or remove the "." from your bucket name for it to work correctly.

Comment: I have had this same problem with django/heroku/amazon-s3 and removing the "." from our bucket names sorted it for us.  Didn't know about the ~/.boto wordaround though, good one.

Answer (score 4):

The **boto** package doesn't fully support S3 buckets with dots in the name, because of SSL certificate scope.

Either create and use a new bucket without a dot, like "shuboymedia", or add this monkey patch in your settings:

```
import ssl
if hasattr(ssl, '_create_unverified_context'):
    ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
```